# How do I most effectively prevent my normally-distributed random variable from being zero?

Tags: c++, random, tr1, montecarlo, normal-distribution

I'm writing a Monte Carlo algorithm, in which at one point I need to divide by a random variable. More precisely: the random variable is used as a step width for a difference quotient, so I actually first multiply something by the variable and then again divide it out of some locally linear function of this expression. Like

```
double f(double);

std::tr1::variate_generator<std::tr1::mt19937, std::tr1::normal_distribution<> >
  r( std::tr1::mt19937(time(NULL)),
     std::tr1::normal_distribution<>(0) );

double h = r();
double a = ( f(x+h) - f(x) ) / h;
```

This works fine most of the time, but fails when `h=0`. Mathematically, this is not a concern because in any finite (or, indeed, countable) selection of normally-distributed random variables, all of them will be nonzero with probability 1. But in the digital implementation I will encounter an `h==0` every ≈2³² function calls (regardless of the mersenne twister having a period longer than the universe, it still outputs ordinary `long`s!).

It's pretty simple to avoid this trouble, at the moment I'm doing

```
double h = r();
while (h==0) h=r();
```

but I don't consider this particularly elegant. Is there any better way?

---

The function I'm evaluating is actually not just a simple ℝ->ℝ like `f` is, but an ℝᵐxℝⁿ -> ℝ in which I calculate the gradient in the ℝᵐ variables while numerically integrating over the ℝⁿ variables. The whole function is superimposed with unpredictable (but "coherent") noise, sometimes with specific (but unknown) outstanding frequencies, that's what gets me into trouble when I try it with fixed values for `h`.

Comment: Work out the analytic derivative and use that for very small h?

Comment: What if h is extremely small but not zero? Does your calculation produce a reasonable answer?

Comment: @Mr E I wish I could do this, but `f` is much too complicated.

Comment: @Alan for very small `h` it gives me increasingly big computation errors, but since these numbers occur very seldom that's not a problem.

Comment: How about using logarithmic step size? Or Runge-kutta methods?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you computing derivatives using a normally distributed random variable?

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure if the normal distribution is really the best, it's just the one that first came to my mind, as it's sort of the canonical distribution for everything. I do need random values because any fixed `h` gives me systematic errors.

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Is there any extra information about this function f? Some context might help us to steer you towards a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your way seems elegant enough, maybe a little different:

```
do {
    h = r();
} while (h == 0.0);
```

Comment: To be honest, if you just want to make sure h is never zero, this would be one of the most effective ways to do it. I'd just wrap this in a function and then do something like `h = RandomNonZero()` in the code

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of two normally-distributed random variables is the Cauchy distribution. The Cauchy distribution is one of those nasty distributions with an infinite variance. Very nasty indeed. A Cauchy distribution will make a mess of your Monte Carlo experiment.

In many cases where the ratio of two random variables is computed, the denominator is not normal. People often use a normal distribution to approximate this non-normally distributed random variable because

- normal distributions are usually so easy to work with,
- usually have such nice mathematical properties,
- the normal assumption appears to be more or less correct, and
- the real distribution is a bear.

Suppose you are dividing by distance. Distance is semi-positive definite by definition, and is often positive definite as a random variable. So right off the bat distance can never be normally distributed. Nonetheless, people often assume a normal distribution for distance in cases where the mean is much, much larger than the standard deviation. When this normal assumption is made you need to protect against those non-real values. One simple solution is a truncated normal.

Comment: I'm not calculating the ratio of two normally-distributed variables. It's the ratio of a random variable and some deterministic function of this variable.

Comment: Why the drive-by downvote? Leave a comment so the answer can be improved.

Comment: I have left a comment, and it was not replied to. – Maybe it's not the right way of deciding when to downvote: it is actually not because I dislike this answer, but because I cannot see how the answer is related to my question, nor why people upvote it. If you explain, I will of course think this over.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve normal distribution you have to either exclude 0 or assign 0 to a new previously non-occurring value. Since the second is most likely not possible in the finite ranges of computer science the first is our only option.

Comment: "If you want to preserve normal distribution you have to either exclude 0 or assign 0 to a new previously non-occurring value" that's what I would prefer to do. Is it really impossible? For even though we have finite ranges, still not all the values do occur, if only because there are less 32-bit-integers than there are `double` numbers between -1 an 1.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to compute, perhaps something like this would work:

```
double h = r();
double a;
if (h != 0)
    a = ( f(x+h) - f(x) ) / h;
else
    a = 0;
```

If `f` is a linear function, this should (I think?) remain continuous at h = 0.

You might also want to instead consider trapping division-by-zero exceptions to avoid the cost of the branch. *Note that this may or may not have a detrimental effect on performance* - benchmark both ways!

On Linux, you will need to build the file that contains your potential division by zero with `-fnon-call-exceptions`, and install a SIGFPE handler:

```
struct fp_exception { };

void sigfpe(int) {
  signal(SIGFPE, sigfpe);
  throw fp_exception();
}

void setup() {
  signal(SIGFPE, sigfpe);
}

// Later...
    try {
        run_one_monte_carlo_trial();
    } catch (fp_exception &) {
        // skip this trial
    }
```

On Windows, use SEH:

```
__try 
{ 
    run_one_monte_carlo_trial();
} 
__except(GetExceptionCode() == EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO ? 
         EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER : EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH)
{ 
    // skip this trial
}
```

This has the advantage of potentially having less effect on the fast path. There is no branch, although there may be some adjustment of exception handler records. On Linux, there may be a small performance hit due to the compiler generating more conservative code for for `-fnon-call-exceptions`. This is less likely to be a problem if the code compiled under `-fnon-call-exceptions` does not allocate any automatic (stack) C++ objects. It's also worth noting that this makes the case in which division by zero *does* happen VERY expensive.

Comment: `(f(x+h) - f(x)) / h` looks a lot like a derivation. A derivation of 0 has many properties, of which some might be unwanted in a calculation like this.

Comment: Indeed; I suppose the question is, mathematically, what should the result, in fact, be when h = 0?

Comment: When h is zero, or rather as you approach h in terms of a limit, you should get the derivative f'(x). The code example you have above is actually mathematically incorrect.

Comment: While it's true that `a=0` is wrong in the case `h==0`, I will still keep this "solution" in mind: one incorrect 0 (unlike the incorrect `NAN` I get without checking!) does not hurt at all, and it looks to me like this code might be a little bit faster then mine because it avoids a branch misprediction.

Answer (score 0):

A function (f(x+h)-f(x))/h has a limit as h->0 and therefore if you encounter h==0 you should use that limit. The limit would be f'(x) so if you know the derivative you can use it.

If what you are actually doing is creating number of discrete points though that approximate a normal distribution, and this is good enough for your distribution, create it in a way that none of them will actually have the value 0.

Comment: "has a limit" only (by definition) if `f` is differentiable at `x`. It might not be.